# I am getting state undefined error when reloading page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Everything is fine the first time but get error and undefined state the time I refresh the page
and also if I comment the h1 and p tags and uncomment then the error resolves and hits again I refresh

**Here is my code**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  var [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=kolkata&units=metric&appid=907c99e1a96b5d38487d8d9c19b413fc"
    )
      .then((doc) => {
        return doc.json();
      })
      .then((doc) => {
        setState(doc);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="welcome">
        <h1>
          {state.list[0].main.temp}
          <sup> o</sup>C
        </h1>
        <p>Feels Like {state.list[0].main.feels_like}</p>
        <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50d.png" alt="haze" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state is an empty object Initially ,you have to put a check ,like I did below.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  var [state, setState] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=kolkata&units=metric&appid=907c99e1a96b5d38487d8d9c19b413fc"
    )
      .then((doc) => {
        return doc.json();
      })
      .then((doc) => {
        setState(doc);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="welcome">
      {Object.keys(state).length>0?<><h1>
          {state.list[0].main.temp}
          <sup> o</sup>C
        </h1>
        <p>Feels Like {state.list[0].main.feels_like}</p></>:""}
        
        <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50d.png" alt="haze" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

or If you want to avoid `Object.keys` make default state `null`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    function App() {
      var [state, setState] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetch(
          "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=kolkata&units=metric&appid=907c99e1a96b5d38487d8d9c19b413fc"
        )
          .then((doc) => {
            return doc.json();
          })
          .then((doc) => {
            setState(doc);
          });
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div className="welcome">
          {state?<><h1>
              {state.list[0].main.temp}
              <sup> o</sup>C
            </h1>
            <p>Feels Like {state.list[0].main.feels_like}</p></>:""}
            
            <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50d.png" alt="haze" />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

UseEffect is called when the component is completely rendered for the first time, so when you use state.list[0].main.attribute, you're calling an undefined, because your initial state is {}.
Try this:

```
<div className="welcome">
    <h1>
      {state.list[0] ? state.list[0].main.temp : ""}
      <sup> o</sup>C
    </h1>
    <p>Feels Like {state.list[0] ? state.list[0].main.feels_like : ""}</p>
    <img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50d.png" alt="haze" />
</div>
```

Comment: does the state gets reinitialized when a page is refreshed??

Comment: No, It doesn't get re-initialized after a refresh!